# Unable To Launch Firefox Driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have checked YouTube & Google for solutions to this error. But I have not been able to get one.

Please, I get this error when I write some code to launch the Firefox driver:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll

Additional information: The geckodriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace FireFox_Driver_Launch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.starwoodhotels.com/preferredguest/account/enroll/index.html");

        }
    }
}
```

I have added the selenium webdriver package from "Manager Nuget Packages" as well.

I have searched this site & Google for a solution. But, I have not gotten a solution yet.

The firefox browser is installed on the PC.

I have downloaded the geckodriver. Please, how do I put it in the PATH?

I believe it should be in the System Environment variables ?

I have also installed Selenium.Firefox.Webdriver.

In addition, I downloaded the gecko driver & put it in the project folder. Still getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the folder where `geckodriver.exe` (the one you downloaded) is located is on your systems `PATH`. Here's a tutorial about how to add a folder to `PATH`: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

Download selenium support drivers via nuget too.
If it didnt work go to http://sqaplus.blogspot.be/2017/01/error-message-on-selenium-3-with-firefox.html?m=1 and see how to initialize firefox driver with selenium 2

Answer (score 0):

**First** Update your Firefox Browser to the latest version.

**Second** you need need to download the ***geckodriver.exe*** from the below url as per your system configuration.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

**Third** write the below code to start the Firefox Browser.

```
//Give the path of the geckodriver.exe    
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64","geckodriver.exe")

//Give the path of the Firefox Browser        
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

**Note:** Assumption you are running selenium 3.0.1

Comment: Many Thanks.. I am using Selenium 2.0.  But it is working now.. Many Thanks..... Much Appreciated...